# Contact Form plugin - Error loading 404 Pages

Tags: 404-page, plugin-contactform

So I have a contact form in my layout (just using the contact form plugin from the Craft guys) and on 404 pages I'm getting the following:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("getErrors") on a string variable ("") in "_layout"

What's the best way around that and to still get the contact form to show up on an 404 page?

Many thanks in advance!

Template code is in the footer of _layout.html and looks like this:

```
<!-- unrelated stuff here... -->

<!-- CONTACT -->

    {% set asset = globalContact.contactBackground.first() %}
    <section id="contact" class="strip contact" style="background-image: url({{ asset.url }});" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2" data-stellar-responsive="true" data-stellar-horizontal-offset="0">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>
                <span>{{ globalContact.contactPreHeader }}</span><br />
                {{ globalContact.contactHeader }}
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            {% macro errorList(errors) %}
                {% if errors %}
                    <ul class="errors">
                        {% for error in errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endmacro %}

            {% from _self import errorList %}
            <form method="post" action="" class="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                {{ getCsrfInput() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thanks">

                <div class="contact-name">
                    <input type="text" id="fromName" name="fromName" placeholder="Name" />
                    {% if message is defined %}{{ errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}{% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="contact-email">
                    <input type="text" id="fromEmail" name="fromEmail" placeholder="Email" />
                    {% if message is defined %}{{ errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}{% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="contact-phone">
                    <input type="text" id="phone" name="message[Phone]" placeholder="Phone" />
                </div>
                <div class="contact-message">
                    <textarea rows="8" cols="40" id="message" name="message[body]" placeholder="Message">{% if message is defined %}{{ message.message }}{% endif %}</textarea>
                    {% if message is defined %}{{ errorList(message.getErrors('message')) }}{% endif %}
                </div>
                <input id="shewbotsshew" name="shewbotsshew" type="text">
                <div class="contact-submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

<!-- unrelated stuff here... -->
```

Comment: I'm guessing you've got the contact form code in a footer or header include on your site?  Can you update the question with the template code?

Comment: Done - hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anywhere you've currently got something that looks like this:

```
{% if message is defined %}{{ errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}{% endif %}
```

Try changing that to:

```
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}
```

And you'll want to do that for the other attributes, too ('fromName', etc.).

Comment: FWIW, updated the example code here to reflect the change, too: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#usage